# How to set SPARK_LOCAL_IP addresses

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, ubuntu, hdfs

I have a word count program on eclipse using Maven and Scala. After exporting the jar file and trying to run it on terminal (on Ubuntu)
I got an unexpected result

My path spark is

```
home/amel/spark
```

my path hadoop is

```
/usr/local/hadoop
```

my commands are
    su hadoopusr //i enter my password
then i enter this commande
    start-all.sh
 then i enter my spark file where the jar has been save and i run this command

```
 spark-submit --class bd.spark_app.first.wordcount --master yarn -- 
    master local[2] SparkExample.jar
```

r

### ** keep in mind I have a file in my HDFS called "sampledata" the file i will be running the word-count program**

---

this is the code i have on eclipse( i am using a maven project with scala ide)
package bd.spark_app

```
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.rddToOrderedRDDFunctions
    object first {
    def main ( args:Array[String] ) ={

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("wordcount")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sampledata = sc.textFile("/home/hadoopusr/sampledata")

    val result = sampledata.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(words => (words, 
    1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
    result.collect.foreach(println)

    result.saveAsTextFile("outputfile")

    sc.stop()
    }
    }
```

---

I expected this  result

```
(me,4)
(you,3)
(food,2)
(cat,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spark-submit --class bd.spark_app.first.wordcount --master yarn -- 
    master local[2] SparkExample.jar
```

this command is wrong there are 2 masters one is local and another is yarn.

second thing is you  `SparkExample.jar` is NOT there in the path where you are trying to execute spark-submit thats the reason classnot found exception.

please correct all these. please refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: i have moved the jar file to where i execute the spark-submit and this is what has came up.. most of the errors have been gone but i still have a problem with the spark ip address 19/05/26 01:07:18 WARN Utils: Your hostname, amel-Satellite-C850-B374 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1, but we couldn't find any external IP address!
19/05/26 01:07:18 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address